# Masking seems not working for missing values problem in LSTM

Tags: keras, lstm, rnn

I am trying to use LSTM to predict time series in keras. My input data shape is (1000,6,1)(samples,timesteps,features). There is some missing data in different timesteps. For example,[2,1,1]=NaN,[3,4,1]=NaN. First, I normalize all these data between (0,1)
Then I try to use fillNan to replace these Nan by special values(-1 for example). Finally, I use Masking to escape the special values.
My code is like that:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Masking(mask_value=1.5,input_shape=(train_X.shape[1], train_X.shape[2])))
model.add(LSTM(32))
model.add(Dense(3))
model.compile(loss='mae', optimizer='adam')
model.fit(train_X, train_y, epochs=50, batch_size=72,validation_data=(test_X, test_y), verbose=2, shuffle=False)
```

When I choose different special values, the outcomes changed and I don't know where is the problem. train_X.shape=(700,6,1),train_y.shape=(300,3).
Is it because there is also NaN in the trian_y which is not Masked?

Comment: Sorry in the code I use 1.5.

Comment: Welcome to DS StackExchange. Can you update your question?

Comment: Do you still have NaN's in your dataset? Or are they all substituted with 1.5 values?

Comment: No, I replaced all the NaN's in my dataset.

Comment: Please mask or delete all your missing values, in all your sets. Then try to run the same model with different masking values, and check whether you observe any difference.

Comment: My train_X is 'array([[[1.5000000e+00],
        [1.5000000e+00],
        [0.0000000e+00],
        [0.0000000e+00],
        [7.3684210e-01],
        [6.5915489e-01]],

       [[1.5000000e+00],
        [1.5000000e+00],
        [2.6436709e-04],
        [0.0000000e+00],
        [4.3859649e-01],
        [7.0985913e-01]],...]]]

Comment: I think all the missing values are replaced by 1.5, So ,did the Masking layer in my model remove them?